¿Cómo puedo solucionar cuando me sale este mensaje? no me permite ver la estructura para diseñar la tabla
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

¿Qué versión de ssms estás usando? ¿A qué base de datos y versión te estás conectando?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para la mejor experiencia de usuario siempre usa la más reciente versión de SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Actualmente la versión más reciente es 20.1 y la puedes descargar en este enlace. Si estas usando SQL Server 2022, SSMS 19 o mayor es requerido, y mejor si descargas SSMS 20.1.
Si estas usando una versión de SQL Server muy vieja, entonces puedes descargar SSMS version 16 a 19 desde este otro enlace. Estas versiones viejas de SSMS son más compatibles con versiones de SQL Server ya no soportadas por Microsoft.
